# How can I detect if device is in Airplane mode?

Tags: android, android-networking

I want to detect if my device is in Airplane mode in order to cancel active network operations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }       
}
```